# Complex JQL query in jira automation

Tags: automation, jira, jql

I want to close epic automatically when the last issue is closed.
The first condition after trigger (closing the issue) is a query which checks if parent epic contains only closed tasks

```
issueFunction in issuesinEpics("NOT issueFunction in EpicsOf("status != Closed")")
```

This query doesn't work and I can't understand why
Is it because of the issueFunction putted into another issueFunction?
Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you try 

issueFunction in issuesInEpics("NOT issueFunction in EpicsOf(\"status != Closed\")")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @HirokSarker! It works!

`issueFunction in issuesInEpics("NOT issueFunction in EpicsOf(\"status != Closed\")")`

One should use a backslash before quotes in the function that is nested in another function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).